# myData method cannot be resolved to a variable error

Tags: java, methods

When I write myData method, its gives an error that It cannot be resolved to a variable. Here is the code.

```
private class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String myXmlData; 

    protected String doInBackground(String...urls) {
        try { 

            **myData** = downloadXML(urls[0]); 

        } catch(IOException e) {
                return "Unable to download XML file.";
            }


        return"";

    }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          Log.d("OnPostExecute", myXmlData);
          textView.setText(myXmlData);
```

Comment: Which probably means that `downloadXML()` with param `urls[0]` does not return anything, therefore **myData** is empty. You should show more of you code.

Comment: .... and tell us the programming language

Comment: You are not declaring **myData** (can you even declare a variable with *'s in Java?) before trying to set a value to it. Try declaring it first like `String **myData**`. But I'd remove the *'s aswell.

Comment: @simpe I added ** just to show that which one is giving an error. But Thanks for your help.

Comment: What library gives you @downloadXML@?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

You are referring to a local variable 'myData' , but your instance variable is called myXmlData. rename one of them.

I hope those stars are just a formatting issue?

Comment: You are absolutely right.. That was the exact error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Re-name the variable `myData` to `myXmlData`. In Java, you cannot initiate a variable before declaring it.

```
String myData;

...

myData = downloadXML(urls[0]);
```